# CSS selector priority from different stylesheet files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a form with input and textarea elements.  I am using bootstrap along with my own site.css.  The site.css is before the boostrap.css in the markup.  I have a css rule in the site css that looks like this:

```
.formcontainer input, textarea {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

The form elements also have the form-control class from bootstrap applied to them.  The problem is that the input elements prioritize the rule from my site css and apply the background color correctly.  However, for the textarea elements the bootstrap class is prioritized over the rule from my site.css.  All form elements are wrapped in the same div containers with the same clasess applied.  I can't make sense of why the elements are getting the rules prioritized differently.

Here's an example of the markup where the input gets the background color but the textarea doesn't:

```
<div id="formpart2" class="formcontainer">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Email</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control invalid" fieldrequired>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Contact Instructions</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="15" fieldrequired></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've encountered a few things like this with Bootstrap.  It comes from the CSS property '!important'.  This can be added to a style up the list of the cascade and not be overwritten as it works its way down.  Bootstrap has a few things that are tagged as important and therefore take priority.  Try adding your own !important.  Here's a fiddle example. https://jsfiddle.net/0fqsm8jq/

Comment: @Dean You ***don't*** use `!important`. Your suggestion is really, and I mean *really* , bad. Cases do exist where usage of `!important` is legitimate. I bet you never encountered one of them. Recommending to solve a css loading prioirity problem with the usage of `!important` is about the worst advice you could possibly give OP.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow You probably want this selector instead `.formcontainer input, .formcontainer textarea { ... }`. Otherwise your rule targets any `input` element that is a descendant of and element with the class `.formcontainer`, and on top of that any textarea whatsoever (no parent with a certain class required here). Also note that this makes the rule for textarea less specific.

Comment: I considered using !important but decided against it.  It's really kind of a lazy hack/last resort.

Comment: @connexo You nailed it, my syntax was wrong.  You should submit that as the answer.

Comment: Even though my answer holds a more detailed explanation of what apparently was causing your troubles, I recommend you mark Jack's answer as correct since he was a) faster and b) corrects your in the order you load your css files. Also doublecheck if @Pranesh Ravi nailed your problem even more precisely.

Comment: @connexo Sorry, man, you're just going to have to accept that you're correct.  It was pointing out that my selector was applying correctly to the input elements but not the textarea because I didn't include the .formcontainer class with the textarea.  I had some crazy notion of the context of the .formcontainer class be "distributed" to all elements after it.  Not sure why I even thought that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap, you might find a rule that starts something like this:

```
.formcontainer input, 
.formcontainer textarea {
    /* whatever */
}
```

In your attempt to *overwrite* that, you forgot the context for textarea:

```
.formcontainer input, 
textarea {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

This makes your rules for textarea less specific than Bootstraps's rule, so even if you load the css files in the correct order, your textarea style won't overwrite Bootstrap's textarea style (assuming you are in a `.formcontainer` context).

I highly recommend you learn more about [CSS specificity](http://cssspecificity.com/). ***Very*** fundamental if you ever want to work with CSS.

Comment: Bootstrap defines the **form-control** class and that was overriding my rule because I didn't format my rule selector correctly (it needed to be in the format of your first rule definition).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> The site.css is before the boostrap.css in the markup.

There's your problem. The way CSS works, rules that appear later (either within one sheet or in terms of multiple sheets being included) will overwrite rules that appear before them. Switch your markup so your custom styles come last - ie, include `bootstrap.css` *before* `site.css`.

(Also, bear in mind that `textarea` is a pretty generic selector. Did you mean `.formcontainer textarea`?)

Comment: This doesn't explain why it selects my (i.e site.css) rule for input elements but doesn't for textarea elements.  Also, as you can see from my rule I am using `.formcontainer textarea`.

Comment: I think I see now (because of @connexo comment) what you were saying about the textarea selector.

Answer (score 2):

The css engine always prioritize `.class` and `#id` over `tag-name`. The problem with your style is, your are using the tag name `textarea` which has a class `form-control` to style. So, the css engine will prioritize `.form-control` over `tag-name`. See the following examples.

**Won't Work**

```css
.formcontainer input,
textarea {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="formpart2" class="formcontainer">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control invalid" fieldrequired>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Contact Instructions</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="15" fieldrequired></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Will Work**

```css
input.form-control,
textarea.form-control {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="formpart2" class="formcontainer">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control invalid" fieldrequired>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Contact Instructions</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="15" fieldrequired></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Pranesh, this is a great answer as well and gives a good alternative solution.